# How to sniff bluetooth packets in C?

Tags: c, bluetooth, sniffing

I would like to capture all bluetooth packets received by my bluetooth adapter on x86 Ubuntu with a simple C program. Sniffing TCP/IP packets is as simple as this:

```c
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
char buf[65536];
while (1) {
    ssize_t bytes_read = read(sock, buf, 65536);
    write(1, buf, bytes_read);
}
```

`man 2 socket` lists `AF_BLUETOOTH` as domain, so I thought it might be as simple as `socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_RAW, 0)`. However, this does not work, just like `socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_RAW, BTPROTO_HCI)` (whereas `BTPROTO_HCI` is from *libbluetooth-dev*). No errors occur (`socket()` and `read()` do not return -1), yet no packets are intercepted, although tcpdump does intercept some.

I found the source code of *libpcap* (tcpdump) for handling bluetooth, but don't really get it: https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/blob/master/pcap-bt-linux.c#L150-L402

Comment: Not sure every radio will even support it. Can you do with Wireshark as in https://hackaday.com/2021/03/23/a-crash-course-on-sniffing-bluetooth-low-energy/ ?

Comment: Yes, Wireshark and tcpdump work as expected